# Stringentness of Melava Malka Meal

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah

How stringently is the Melava Malka meal to be taken into consideration?

For example, if it would cause a great deal of Bittul Torah, would one still need to fulfill the meal? (which is not the case for a meal of Shabbos, in comparison).

Answer (score 3):

R Ari Enkin brings a number of sources on the topic [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/dalet-amot-of-halacha/melave-malka/). He writes it is a mitzva worth every effort but ultimately optional.

> **It is considered a great mitzva to prepare and partake of a special
>   meal following the conclusion of Shabbat.** [...]
>
> The melave malka meal should preferably be held within fours hours
>   following the conclusion of Shabbat though it may be held any time
>   until midnight. **Under extenuating circumstances one can still fulfill
>   the mitzva of eating the melave malka meal until dawn Sunday morning.**
>   Although one may not have an appetite to eat yet another meal
>   following the conclusion of a gastronomically filled Shabbat **one
>   should nevertheless make every effort to do so.**
>
> **Ultimately however, partaking of the melave malka meal is essentially
>   optional and not an outright obligation** (Shulchan Aruch Harav 300:1,
>   Mishna Berura 300:2).
>
> **Some authorities say that if need be one can
>   discharge the melave malka ‘”meal”‘ with merely a hot drink** (Piskei
>   Teshuvot 300:1).

Comment: How does this address bitul torah??

Comment: I think it is quite clear that if it is optional and can be discharged with a hot drink, then learning Torah is a very valid way to spend motsei shabbat. Beyond that, as usual on MY, an individual ruling taking the personal circumstances in question will require a rav close to the OP.